# How to add component in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a Vue 2.5.2 app with vue-cli.

I tried creating my first component (`<jsontree />`) which works on its own but I can't figure out how to register to use in another component (`<HelloWorld>`)

This is the error message I receive:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <jsontree> - did you register the component correctly? For recursi§ve components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

this is `HelloWorld`'s template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <jsontree />
  </div>
</template>
```

it works when i navigate to it "directly", this is my routes file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import JsonTree from '@/components/jsonTree'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/tree',
      name: 'Tree',
      component: JsonTree
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `<script>` part.

also, it is customary, but not mandatory, to write with `kebab-case` inside the template.

Vue engine is responsible for allowing you to write with `kebab-case` inside the template, even when you imported it as `camelCase` within your `script`

see the code:

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <json-tree />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jsonTree from './jsonTree.vue'  // or wheatever location this component is residing.
export default {
  components: {jsonTree}
}
</script>
```